# Cron on XAMPP (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, cron, xampp

I have installed XAMPP server on my Mac OS, how to setup a cron job on it?

My requirement is that i want to call a php script at regular intervals .

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a good [article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) here how to setup cron job on Mac OS X

you would have to edit a textfile(crontabtaskfile)and add for example

```
0      */1     *       *       *      php path/to/yourphp.php
```

this would give you a task running every hour (1:00, 2:00) .

and use `crontab crontabtaskfile`

Comment: It may be necessary to specify the path to 'php'. I'm using XAMPP for *WinXP* and php.exe is NOT in the PATH.

Comment: Cron is for mac, linux not windows.

Comment: The link is useless, goes to site homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Cronnix
http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/
or the command line for editing cron tabs.